# Unity is locked, you can not remove icons or move them

Tags: unity, 13.10, icons, panel, lock

Issue the following, I can not change the order of icons on the unity, nor their sleep or anything to add that it would be "locked", the programs run.

Answer (score 0):

You seems using unity-2d , just logoff and select unity-3d and try .

Logoff ---->

[image]

Click on the icon in the picture.

Choose 3d and login .

Now try , and reply .

Comment: I do not see this icon

Comment: no it is normal ubuntu

Comment: if you are using 13.10 , you should be using unity 3d , maybe it can be you vga .

Comment: 5 minut ago, everything was alright. My computer is not old

Comment: unfortunately not